# Adblocker detection using gpt callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, double-click

I have seen a few methods to detect if a user has ad blocking enabled, such as loading a ads.js file and changing a variable once that has loaded.  Is there a way to detect this simply in the google doubleclick gpt callback?

Basically I just want to look into some ad view discrepancies and see how many users not seeing ads have an ad blocker enabled.  I noticed with both ad blockers I am trying the gpt callback is still fired and the iframes are loaded with empty body tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't had any luck figuring out a way to detect an ad-block in gpt.  I modified another solution I saw loading an ads.js file.  Below I am loading the ads.js then loading another external file from the same server to invoke the call to the function to track whether the user has an ad blocker enabled.  This could be done with a settimeout but I feel doing it this way reduces the chance to run into async issues with ads.js not being loaded.  Check vars for typos if you are going to use this I had to strip out a brand name.

**inline js**

```
  // Adblock detection with external file.
  var adsEnabled = false;
  adBlock = function() {
    // Omniture reporting for ad blocking.
    if(!adsEnabled) {
      document.getElementById('ad-blocker').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-box">Ad blocker enabled, no ads should appear.</div>';
      // Omniture ad block var to false.
    } else {
      document.getElementById('ad-blocker').innerHTML = '<div class="success alert-box">Ad blocker disabled, you should see ads.</div>';
      // Omniture ad block var to true.
    }
  };
  // Ad blockers will block this file.
  document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="/js/ads.js"><\/scr' + 'ipt>');
  // adBlock() is called from an external file to prevent async issues.
  document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="/js/adblockInit.js"><\/scr' + 'ipt>');
```

**ads.js**

```
adsEnabled = true;
```

**adblockInit.js**

```
adBlock();
```

**html**

```
<div id="ad-blocker">No data.</div>
```

**Use this method for script blocking ad blockers.**

```
<script src="http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js" onload="callback()" onerror="error()"></script>

function callback() {
  // in this case you will need to verify the gpt object isn't blank for some ad blockers in chrome
}

function error() {
  // most script blocking ad blockers will end up here.  All script blocking ad blockers (ghostery, disconnect) I have seen in firefox end up here.
}
```